# JUnit tests in VS Code not producing any output

Tags: junit

I am working on a Java project in VS Code, and I have written some JUnit tests. When I try to run these tests, I don't get any output in the terminal or the test results pane. I'm not sure what's wrong or how to troubleshoot this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qyPw.png)

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Restarting VS Code.
- Running the tests from the terminal using `gradle test`.
- Checking the Java Test Runner extension settings.